# AJAX and PHP link

Tags: jquery, ajax

After reading several tutorials, I still have difficulties to link my PHP with my Ajax method. Is there a way to get the variable `$errors[]` from my PHP file into my HTML page with my `function(data)`?

Thank you in advance!

Here is my code in PHP:

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($_POST)){
    $errors = array();
    require_once 'inc/db.php';
    function str_random($length){
    $alphabet ="0123456789azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbnAZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN";
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($alphabet, $length)), 0, $length);}

if(empty($_POST['username']) || !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', $_POST['username'])){
    $errors['username'] = "Votre pseudo n'est pas valide (alphanumérique)";
} else {
    $req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?');
    $req->execute([$_POST['username']]);
    $user = $req->fetch();
    if($user){
        $errors['username'] = 'Ce pseudo est déjà pris';
    }
}

if(empty($_POST['email']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $errors['email'] = "Votre email n'est pas valide";
} else {
    $req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ?');
    $req->execute([$_POST['email']]);
    $user = $req->fetch();
    if($user){
        $errors['email'] = 'Cet email est déjà utilisé pour un autre compte';
    }
}

if(empty($_POST['password']) || $_POST['password'] != $_POST['password_confirm']){
    $errors['password'] = "Vous devez rentrer un mot de passe valide";
}

if(empty($errors)){

$req = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users SET username = ?, password = ?, email = ?, confirmation_token = ?");
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$token = str_random(60);
$req->execute([$_POST['username'], $password, $_POST['email'], $token]);
$user_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
mail($_POST['email'], 'Confirmation de votre compte', "Afin de valider votre compte merci de cliquer sur ce lien\n\nhttp://localhost/Type&GoSite/confirm?id=$user_id&token=$token");
$_SESSION['flash']['success'] = 'Un email de confirmation vous a été envoyé pour valider votre compte';
header('Location: login.php');
exit();

}

}
?>
<?php if(!empty($errors)){
header('Content-Type: application/json; Charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($errors);
exit();}?>

<?php if(!empty($errors)): ?>
    <div class="flash2">
        <h3>Vous n'avez pas rempli le formulaire correctement</h3>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($errors as $error): ?>
               <li><?= $error; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here is my code in HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <br><br><br>
    <h1>S'inscrire</h1>

    <div id="resultat"></div>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Pseudo</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Mot de passe</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Confirmez votre mot de passe</label>
            <input type="password" id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">M'inscrire</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is my JS (I'm using jQuery 1.7.2):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();
        $.post('register.php', {
            login : $("#username").val(),
            password : $("#password").val(),
            password_confirm : $("#password_confirm").val(),
            email : $("#email").val()
        },
        function (data) {
            if (data && data.length > 0) {
                // show errors in your HTML somewhere
                $("#resultat").html("voici les erreurs");
            } else {
                $("#resultat").html("<p>Un email de confirmation vous a été envoyé pour valider votre compte");
           } 
            },   

    'JSON'
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: It's extremely laudable that you are using parameterized SQL and store passwords in hashed form. Please also use a salt value when calculating the hash (see [example in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#example-960))! (You will need to store the salt in the database next to the user account and use it for comparing passwords.)

Answer (score 0):

Structured data is typically transferred in JSON form.

Therefore when there are errors, convert them to JSON in PHP and send them to the client. Don't forget to set the correct `Content-Type` header:

```
if(!empty($errors)){
    header('Content-Type: application/json; Charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($errors);
    exit();
}
```

On the receiving end the `$errors` array will arrive and jQuery will helpfully decode the JSON for you, turning it into a regular JS array:

```
$.post('register.php', {
    login : $("#username").val(),
    password : $("#password").val(),
    password_confirm : $("#password_confirm").val(),
    email : $("#email").val()
}).done(function (errors) {
    if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
        // show errors in your HTML somewhere
        $("#resultat").html("...");
    } else {
        $("#resultat").html("<p>Un email de confirmation vous a été envoyé pour valider votre compte");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I have edited my code as per your comments but it was not working. So I have tried something else but it does not work either. You can find my new edited code above. Where are my mistakes? thank you again!

Comment: My variable $error from php does not appear in my html page even if there is conversion to JSON.

Comment: No, because jQuery receives it in response to the Ajax request. The browser will not render Ajax responses. What did you expect would happen when you transmit a form via Ajax? (BTW I notice that your submit handler is missing a call to `preventDefault()`.

Comment: yes you are right I have fixed the preventDefault() and the $("#submit").click(function(). Everything works. PHP sends me a response in JSON : email"Votre email n'est pas valide" password" Vous devez rentrer un mot de passe valide". It is on my server of the console.  Howerver it does not appear in my html page. It seems that there is a problem with the conversion of the JSON. Console.log(data) is undefined in my console.

Comment: I have found the mistakes;                                                            function(data){ $("#errors1").html(data.username); $("#errors2").html(data.password); $("#errors3").html(data.email); }, and                                                     <html> <br><br> <div id="errors1"> </div> <div id="errors2"> </div> <div id="errors3"> </div> </html> –

Comment: Nice, kudos for finding out on your own! :)